# Design pattern for telegram bot

Tags: python, design-patterns, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I am currently working on a telegram bot that is going to have many functions and is going to be quite complicated. I currently finished one feature of the bot and the code is already unmanageable.

For example, the conversation handler currently looks like this:

```
# BOT STATES
FIRST, SECOND, THIRD, FOURTH, FIFTH, SIXTH = range(6)
# Callback data
ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, CANCEL = range(5)


conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
    entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', self.start)],
    states={
        FIRST: [
            CallbackQueryHandler(
                self.one, pattern='^' + str(ONE) + '$'),
            CallbackQueryHandler(
                self.cancel, pattern='^' + str(CANCEL) + '$'),
        ],
        SECOND: [
            CallbackQueryHandler(
                self.two, pattern='^' + str(TWO) + '$'),
            # extra handler here
            CallbackQueryHandler(
                self.five, pattern='^' + str(THREE) + '$')
        ],
        THIRD: [
            MessageHandler(Filters.text, self.three)
        ],
        FIFTH: [
            MessageHandler(Filters.text, self.six)
        ],
        FOURTH: [
            MessageHandler(Filters.text, self.four)
        ],
        SIXTH: [
            MessageHandler(Filters.text, self.seven)
        ]

    },
    fallbacks=[CommandHandler('cancel', self.cancel)]
)
```

Where I have to keeping adding more callback data and more states for the bot as the bot gets more and more complicated.

I also have to keep adding more functions to the same .py file to handle use as callback functions:

```
def six(self, update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("Enter name")
    return SIXTH
```

Is there a better way to manage my code? Or a recommended design pattern that I can use to have a easier time managing my project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

design patterns are "recipes" intended to be used to solve known problems.
for example, if you need to notify an object, when another one changes, you can use the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern).

In your situation it seems you might need to rework a bit your architecture, trying to identify the points that can be abstracted with a design pattern.

For example, if you are in the situation in which you receive a lot of events, and you need to keep track and react to a particular sequence, maybe it's worth to consider [state pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern) or the [strategy pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern).

In general the idea is to try both to identify known patterns, and to try to model your software so that you can fall in a known case, that is solved by a design pattern.

Comment: so I am looking for design architecture and not design patterns?

Comment: you are looking for both. there are different layers of design. one the most important example is MVC design pattern, that is an architectural pattern, that hardly can be generalized. OTOH you need to model your code so that it behaves in that way. And then you will have the separation that MVC promises.

Comment: thank you. "MVC design pattern, that is an architectural pattern" I dont understand this part. MVC is both design and architecture? Are there other such patterns that help with architecture and design like MVC?

Comment: MVC is as a design pattern. But in order to implement it, you need to identify what is the model in your case, who is the view, and who is the controller

The reason why this is a bit abstract is that it depends on your specific implementation details.

MVC establishes roles, and tells you what should be the relationship between your objects, realizing a pattern, but this way to see it is more architecture oriented.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: OTOH design patterns contribute to realize your architecture. Hope it makes sense :)

Comment: for example, if you want to implement MVC, it will have effects on the architecture, because in the end that is the effect of MVC: define a loosely coupled architecture.